# Adding udev for embedded linux

Tags: linux, embedded-linux, busybox

I am using an arm processor and linux busybox as my OS. I want to add udev running in my system. The system has mdev. But doesn't seem to fulfill my need. How can I add udev for my system?

thank you.

Comment: Not that I know anything about embedded, but I'm curious - what need does `mdev` not fulfill?

Comment: Hi, I want to mount a usb device based on the port they attached. In udev I can write something like this.             BUS=="usb",ID="1-2", KERNEL=="sd?1" NAME="pen1";                   How can I write it using mdev?